# draw a HTML table using JavaScript: This web page has not been found

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="list"></div>
<div>
  <script>
    var locations = ["Paya Lbar A","Paya Lebar B"];
    var HTML = '<table><tr style="background:#809FFF"><td align="center"><b><font color="royalblue" size=30>Location List</font></b></td></tr>';
    for(j=0;j<locations.length;j=j+1){
      var location = locations[j];
      HTML += "<tr><td align=center>"+location+"</td></tr>";
    }
    HTML += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = HTML;
  </script>
</div>
</body>
```

I just run this single file but I got the error:

`No web page was found for the web address: file:///C:/Users/Li%20Dan/Desktop/Paya%20Lebar%20B`

I totally have no idea, any help??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change the variable name from `location` to something else like `myLocation`. `window.location` tries to navigate to the values in your array in the loop.

Comment: `location` is a keyword in javascript. Use another variable instead and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are define **`HTML Varible or location Variable`** that's why problem is occur. **`HTML, location`** is **`reserve character`**  so i suggest you **`change variable`** name to solve this,

### Check this <kbd>[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hW7G7/1/)</kbd>

```
<div id="list"></div>
<div>
  <script>
    var locations = ["Paya Lbar A","Paya Lebar B"];
    var tbl = '<table><tr style="background:#809FFF"><td align="center"><b><font color="royalblue" size=30>Location List</font></b></td></tr>';
    for( j = 0 ; j < locations.length ; j++){
      tbl += "<tr><td align=center>" + locations[j] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    tbl += "</table>";
    console.log(tbl);
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = tbl;
  </script>
</div>
```

One more things do not declare or assign value to a varible, **`locations[j]`** to easy you take this value so use this way.

Comment: HTML varible? HTML is reserve character? This is so wrong.

Comment: I thought it was just `document.location` and `window.location` that were special. Does a local variable with this name also have the same effect?

Comment: yes location is special not a HTML but first sign i think defined HTML is not a good variable name and i change this name and location variable name change to solve this. so i'm saying.